# Smallest template for a LaTeX Ph.D. thesis?

Tags: templates, thesis

**I am looking for a most minimum template/example for a LaTeX Ph.D. thesis.**

I am going to write a dissertation/Ph.D. thesis.

I use Ubuntu with `pdflatex` (minimum installation of TeX Live). The goal is to keep it smallest as possible for a Ph.D. Thesis, using pdflatex.

The use of no packages (usepackage) would be ideal, if it may be possible.

thank you

Comment: `\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}` ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61028/discussion-on-question-by-ubuntu89234-smallest-template-for-a-latex-ph-d-thesis).

Comment: As others have said in comments now moved to chat, it's really not clear what you mean by 'most minimal' here. Fran's comment above is arguably the shortest one could start from (I'd use `report` but this is a very minor detail). As it stands, either the question is a duplicate of the older one _or_ it's unclear _or_ it's too broad: you need to make it clear what you mean precisely by 'most minimal'.

Comment: Seems like reading an introduction to learn how LaTeX works seems to be a good idea, given the fact you want to write a serious thesis.

Answer (score 5):

A minimal template with custom spacing for chapters and bibliography:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\title{Your thesis}
\author{You}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=1cm,afterskip=2cm]{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
Text \cite{Mittelbach:2004}
\section{Objectives}
More text

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{litteratur}

\end{document}
```

Note: It is a bad idea add a  `\vspace{}` before and after every section level as you show in your comment. Instead, change the chapter format.

Comment: @Fran I'm calm :) you just didn't see the smile on my face: it's still early morning and I'm in need of coffee and the question is closed anyway, so I don't actually care too much

Comment: @Schweinebacke A thesis without references ? I never saw such a thing.... thebibliography is minimal, but specially in thesis that usually have  several pages of references seem a bad idea , and biblatex, well ... may be is better for people that no longer need a template. The custom chapters and the answer itself was because I guessed for the  OP comments that he need a little more.

Comment: @clemens I also forgot the smile `:)`

Comment: "RedeclareSectionCommand" gives error of undefined command. Furthermore pdflatex says that a file _bbl_ is missing :(

Comment: @ubuntu89234 Likely you have an older KOMA-Script which doesn't define `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. The `.bbl` will be missing on a first run _but_ that's not an error, it's just information and is entirely normal.